# How negligible is the time for ofstream

Tags: c++, time, ofstream

I have a C++ program where I do various experiments and during these experiments I output some values to a file using `ofstream`. The structure is basically:

```
 Start timer

 output to a file using ofstream (the output is, at most, a few words)

 do some experimental work

 Stop timer
```

My question, which is a bit broad, is can I ignore the time that the ofstream takes or it's not something negligible ? or I guess it depends ?

Comment: Can you time how long `ostream` takes? That will give you an idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, from your pseudo code, you could just start the timer after the file output :-) But I'm guessing it's not like that in the real app.

Beyond that, it's obviously a matter of "it depends". If you aren't outputting all that much, and the code you're interested in runs for minutes, then the output obviously won't make much of a difference. If, on the other hand, you are trying to catch runtimes measured in microseconds, you'll probably be mostly measuring the ofstream.

You could try doing various magics, like running the actual output on a thread, or just adding your messages to a previously allocated char array and outputting that at the end. However, everything incurs some runtime penalty; nothing is ever free.

Since you're not interested in measuring the actual output time, you could compile a version without the output to do measurements, and a version with the output to debug the code. EDIT: or make that a runtime option. Nothing is ever free, but an "if (OutputEnabled)" is pretty close to "free" :-)

Comment: Comparing with the 'OutputEnablead' version is a great idea as long as the *experiment* is replicable (and it should be). Also instead of an 'if' you could just have '#ifdef OUTPUT_ENABLED'

Comment: Yeah, the #ifdef was the other option with the two different versions. However, depending on the build system, making this distinction might cause some complications, whereas something akin to "--verbose" or "--quiet" (depending on what the default should be) can always be there

Answer (score 2):

It mostly depends from what the `ofstream` does... as long as it just stores data in its internal buffer it will be fast, but if gets its buffer filled and actually call the OS API to perform the write the time spent could be much bigger.

But obviously everything depends on how long does the "experimental work" take in comparison to the IO you perform, both in the case where it just writes the data to the internal buffer and when the stream is flushed; as suggested in the comment, you should time the two things independently, to see how one time compares to the other.

Answer (score 1):

Something is negligible compared to something else. You compare to nothing else in your question.

I had already asked a question here so as to check the validity of my statement below, and the conclusion was that I should not keep such classification, though it still just gives *a rough rough draft evaluation* (that may be false in some cases):

*Stack operations are 10x faster than heap memory creations that are 10x faster than graphical device operations that are 10x faster than I/O operations ( writing to a file on hard drive for example ) that are 10x faster than net communication operation...*

It's is only a rough estimation. Everything has to be re-evaluated each time you code.

If the time passed in the writing to ofstream doesnt impact the whole mechanism then it can be considered negligible.

If it does impact your whole program mechanism, then it cannot be considered negligible. Obviously.